# Automatically pull email addresses from landing page sign-up form

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I'm new to Salesforce Marketing Cloud. I am going to be creating a landing page (outside of marketing cloud) that will have a sign-up form for our e-newsletter. How can I automatically importing email addresses from subscribers who sign-up for my e-newsletter via this landing page, to an existing subscriber list?  Do I use a web service API? AMPscript, etc?

I have done my research and do not have a clue! :(

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the SFMC [SOAP](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/) or [REST API](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/) to add your subscribers.   There are [SDKs](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/) for the popular languages.

[Web Collect](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/web_collect/) could be an option, depending on your configuration.

AMPScript is only for emails and landing pages within the platform.